# Icon disappears from launcher after reboot

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I'm using 11.10.
I've created `/usr/share/applications/idea.desktop` with such content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IntellijIdea

Comment=Idea

Exec=idea

StartupNotify=true

Icon=/usr/java/idea-IU-107.587/bin/idea128.png

Terminal=false

Type=Application
```

Then I opened Dash and typed `idea`. I saw an icon and pressed it. The application started. I clicked with the right mouse button on its icon in the launcher and selected "keep in launcher". When I restarted my notebook, the icon disappeared from the launcher. Where can be the problem?

Comment: note: looks like a typo in the desktop file name, should be ".desktop" with a 'k'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the keep in launcher option (which does not always work for some reason), drag the icon from the Dash to the launcher, and it should remain there in the future.

Comment: Thank you.It worked wtih PhpStorm 6.0 and ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS launcher.